# oracle ogr2ogr import to DB wrong encoding Brazilian shapefile

Tags: oracle, encoding, ogr2ogr

I'm facing a problem while importing a shapefile with ogr2ogr with portuguese-brazilian charset.
The shapefile has been downloaded from OpenStreetMap and is correctly read on QGis.
When I tried to import it through ogr2ogr I got several street names showing wrong enconding.
For example, instead of
`"Ângelo Ferrârio Lopes"` 
i get
`"Ã¿ngelo FerrÃ¡rio Lopes".`

Oracle Database charset is WE8ISO8859P15. Inputs from software interface are correctly saved in the DB.

I tried to setting
`PGCLIENTENCODING=LATIN1`
with same result.

Does anyone have any idea?
Thanks

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'Ângelo Ferrârio'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'iso-8859-15')` returns `'Ã\x82ngelo FerrÃ¢rio'` where `\x85` translates in your example to a replacement character `¿` because it's unprintable  `` (U+0082,  *Break Permitted Here*)…